# Create a bidiagonal matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a specific function from `numpy` or `scipy` in order to easily create a bidiagonal or a tridiagonal matrix?

So far the simplest solution I've come up with is:

```
main_diag = [1,2,3,4,5]
off1 = [1,2,3,4]
np.diag(main_diag) + np.diag(off1, 1)

array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]])
```

Is there some function to do this in one single step?

Comment: Maybe `diags` from scipy? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html

Comment: I wouldn't use `sparse` just to save a bit of typing.

Comment: But looking at the code for `np.diag` I can imagine streamlining the double call with two `res.flat` assignments. Time savings would be minor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sparse.diags`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html) from  scipy. Here's a simple solution for the OP.

```
from scipy import sparse

diags = [range(1, 6), range(1, 5)] 
sparse.diags(diags, [0, 1]).toarray()

array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 5.]])
```

---

To generalise,

```
size = 5
num_diags = 2 # should be < size
diags = [range(1, size+1-i) for i in range(num_diags)] 

sparse.diags(diags, range(num_diags)).toarray()

array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4., 4.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 5.]])
```

Comment: Great thanks! Good to know you can specify multiple offsets in `sparse.diags`

Comment: Sparse has 2 diag creators, one takes a ragged list of values, the other a 'padded' 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you can do that with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def make_diags(diags):
    # Make a linear array for the whole matrix
    n = len(diags[0])
    a = np.zeros(n * n, dtype=diags[0].dtype)
    # Assign each diagonal to the right stride
    step = n + 1
    for i, diag in enumerate(diags):
        a[i:(n - i) * n:step] = diag
    # Reshape
    return a.reshape(n, n)

print(make_diags([np.arange(1, 6), np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(1, 4)]))
# [[1 1 1 0 0]
#  [0 2 2 2 0]
#  [0 0 3 3 3]
#  [0 0 0 4 4]
#  [0 0 0 0 5]]
```

It seems to be faster than using `scipy.sparse.diags`, although not orders of magnitude, so I'm not sure if it's enough to make up for the additional complexity:

```
import scipy.sparse

def make_diags_sparse(diags):
    return scipy.sparse.diags(diags, range(len(diags)), dtype=diags[0].dtype).toarray()

diags = [np.arange(10000 - i) for i in range(1000)]
%timeit make_diags(diags)
# 129 ms ± 439 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit make_diags_sparse(diags)
# 298 ms ± 1.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

EDIT: The function can be edited a bit to add the ability to stack lower diagonals like this:

```
import numpy as np

def make_diags(diags, lower=False):
    n = len(diags[0])
    nn = n * n
    a = np.zeros(nn, dtype=diags[0].dtype)
    step = n + 1
    start, end = (n, 1) if lower else (1, n)
    for i, diag in enumerate(diags):
        a[i * start:nn - i * end:step] = diag
    return a.reshape(n, n)

print(make_diags([np.arange(1, 6), np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(1, 4)], lower=True))
# [[1 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 2 0 0 0]
#  [1 2 3 0 0]
#  [0 2 3 4 0]
#  [0 0 3 4 5]]
```

EDIT 2: Another further edit to allow for arbitrary diagonal indices and shapes, more similar to `scipy.sparse.diags`:

```
import numpy as np

def make_diags(diags, offsets, shape=None):
    if shape is None:
        shape = (len(diags[0]) + abs(offsets[0]),) * 2
    rows, cols = shape
    size = rows * cols
    a = np.zeros(size, dtype=diags[0].dtype)
    step = cols + 1
    d = cols - rows
    for offset, diag in zip(offsets, diags):
        start = max(offset, 0) - min(offset, 0) * cols
        offset2 = d - offset
        end = size - (max(offset2, 0) - min(offset2, 0) * cols)
        a[start:end:step] = diag
    return a.reshape(rows, cols)

print(make_diags([np.arange(1, 4), np.arange(1, 5), np.arange(1, 3)], (-1, 2, 4), (4, 6)))
# [[0 0 1 0 1 0]
#  [1 0 0 2 0 2]
#  [0 2 0 0 3 0]
#  [0 0 3 0 0 4]]
```

Comment: Nice @jdehesa!! Thanks

Comment: `np.diag` uses `res.flat[...]=...` assignment, so `res` can be the desired 2d shape from the start.

Comment: @hpaulj How do you mean? Can you use `np.diag` to set diagonals in an existing array? That would make it simpler but I don't see how... Can you please illustrate?